# Need to insert a custom node edit link in the node template

Tags: theming, nodes

I've removed the tabs 'view and edit' from the node content type display.
I need to provide a custom link to edit the particular node based on user permissions. 
I've used node/%/edit in node tpl but it does'n't work. Can someone help me with the proper method to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your node.tpl.php you have access to current `node` object `$node` and you can get the node id.
You can check permissions for current logged user with [user_access function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7)

So you can do the next thing in your node.tpl.php

```
<?php 
      if (user_access('your_permission_here')){
       //create link for current node edit
       echo l(t('Edit this node'), 'node/' . $node->nid . '/edit');
      }
?>
```

Comment: You also need to check if the user is the author then render the edit link, otherwise anyone with the exact set of permission can see the link.

Comment: Here is a better solution that checks the permission first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33258230/1127583

Answer (score 3):

This did it for me without having to worry about user permissions(default drupal permissions apply)... pasted it in the tpl for getting the edit link.

```
<?php
if (node_access('update',$node)){
print l(t('Edit'),'node/'.$node->nid.'/edit' );
}
?>
```